# ModuleNotFoundError in Airflow using BashOperator

Tags: python, bash, airflow

I want to create a pipeline using Airflow.

1. I have different folders:
   **preprocessing_data** (where I have mycode.py) and mycode.py will use some python scripts available in another folder named **helpers**.
   As mentioned here from mycode.py:

```
from helpers.tags import *
from helpers.useful_functions import formatting_date
```

2. I used a bashoperator with the bash_command below to run mycode.py

```
 bash_command=f"cd /opt/airflow && python preprocessing_data/mycode.py " f"--query-name mycode" f"--execution-date {{{{ ds }}}}"
```

3. In my Dockerfile, I copied my folders as below

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.4-python3.9

COPY --chown=airflow:root . .
COPY --chown=airflow:root helpers/ .
COPY --chown=airflow:root preprocessing_data/ .
```

When I run my pipeline, I got this error in my logs :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

I tried many things but without results. Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter doesn't know anything about your `helpers` package, you can add it to the python path, in this case you be able to import from it.

Suppose that the helpers package is in the folder `/opt/airflow`:

```py
 bash_command=f"export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/airflow && cd /opt/airflow && python preprocessing_data/mycode.py " f"--query-name mycode" f"--execution-date {{{{ ds }}}}"
```